# Angular 9 - ngSwitch not linked

Tags: angular, ng-switch

I got a form that is supposed to change according to the case I selected in a dropdown:[image: dropdown taken]

The type of the room is taken : simple, doubles or triples.

But, although I read about the ngSwitch to display the DOM (a simple form), I cannot link the 2 (types and the ngSwitch)

According to the logic I found online, I put my HTML code and the condition of the switch in the template from my component.ts (it was in a separate HTML file at first but neither works).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-revenue',
  // templateUrl: './revenue.component.html',
  template: `

    <div [ngSwitch]="types.value">
      <div *ngSwitchDefault="''">
        <p>Essai Espace</p>

          <div>
      <form [formGroup]="revenueForm" (ngSubmit)="revenueManager()">

          <div class="form-group">
          <select name="types" id="types" ngModel="types"  class="form-control"  formControlName="types">
            <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type.value">
              {{type.viewValue}}
            </option>
          </select>
          </div>
      </form>
          <pre>{{revenueForm.value | json }}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div *ngSwitchCase="'roomsSimples'">
        <p>Essai Espace</p>

        <form [formGroup]="revenueForm" (ngSubmit)="revenueManager()">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Rooms Simples</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="roomsSimples">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>

        <div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <select name="types" id="types" ngModel="types"  class="form-control"  formControlName="types">
              <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type.value">
                {{type.viewValue}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <pre>
    {{revenueForm.value | json }}
    </pre>
      </div>
  `,

  styleUrls: ['./revenue.component.sass']
})
```

I have declared in my class the types:

```js
export class RevenueComponent implements OnInit {
  revenueForm: FormGroup;

  // doubles = value.roomsDoubles;
  header = "Outils Revenus";

  //Pour les rooms
  types = [
    {value: 'roomsSimples', viewValue: 'Rooms Simples'},
    {value: 'roomsDoubles', viewValue: 'Rooms Doubles'},
  ];
  // type = this.types.values();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.revenueForm = this.fb.group({
      roomsDoubles: [],
      roomsDoublesEnfant: [],
      roomsTriples: [],
      roomsAppartement: [],
      types: [],
    })
  }

  revenueManager() {
    console.log('Données du formulaire...', this.revenueForm.value);
  }
}
```

Though the value of types appears on my render, the modification of the DOM doesn't appear.
Can you please direct me on the right track?
Thanks

Comment: ```[ngSwitch]="types.value"``` types is an array and not an object, so doing ```types.value``` will not work ```types``` can only be accessed by index e.g ```types[0].value ... types[i].value``` from your code it is not very clear what you are attempting to achieve but it looks like you have some logic problem in the way you are organizing the component that goes beyond just the use of ngSwitch, if you can provide more details on what you are trying to achieve, I can help you do it the right way

Comment: Yeah, thanks @h0ss.
First, the hotel keeper selects a type of room displaying the form and the graph of this perticular type of room. He can enter by inputs some information (price, rooms availables,...).

He could then switch to the other types of rooms his hotel consist of.

You might already gave me an input about the array and the object. I tried so many thinks these last few days, I even tried this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `[ngSwitch]="types.value"` **types** is an *Array* and not an *Object*, so doing **types.value** will not work **types** can only be accessed by index e.g `types[0].value`

From your code it is not very clear what you are attempting to achieve but it looks like you have some logic problem in the way you are organizing the component that goes beyond just the use of ngSwitch.

Here is an example of using ngSwitch in the context of what I understand you want to achieve.

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  selectedRoomType: any;
  types = [
    {value: 'roomsSimples', viewValue: 'Rooms Simples'},
    {value: 'roomsDoubles', viewValue: 'Rooms Doubles'},
  ];
}
```

**component.html**

```
<!-- Dropdown to select the room type -->
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Room Types</mat-label>

  <!-- Bind the selection to selectedRoomType -->
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedRoomType" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.value">
      {{type.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<!-- Switch Depending on the type -->
<div [ngSwitch]="selectedRoomType">

  <!-- If type is roomsSimples -->
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'roomsSimples'">
    <strong> Rooms Simple Form </strong>
  </div>

  <!-- If type is roomsDoubles -->
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'roomsDoubles'">
    <strong> Rooms Doubles Form </strong>
  </div>

  <!-- Any other value (including undefined) -->
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <strong> Select a Room Type </strong>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a working stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6uwuux
Please make sure to checkout angular docs https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Also, I suggest using enums for your types, it would make it a lot easier to refactor your code in case your type values change in the future.

Comment: Thanks h0ss. It worked perfectly.
I need to understand more angular. I think I need to practise more on POO in JS, that must slipped through me.

I will check out enums and the link you sent.